# ArrayList is changing index order after copying content of a JSON object

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Lets say that I have a JSON object called fruits and this is the content of it:

```
"fruits":[{
    "name":"natural_one", 
    "kind"{
        0:"apple",
        1:"banana",
        2:"pear"
    }
}];
```

And when I copy the content of the JSONObject in a new ArrayList, the index order changes like the example here below:

```
"fruits":[{
    "kind"{
        1:"banana",
        2:"pear",
        0:"apple"
    },
    "name":"natural_one"
}];
```

What do I do to prevent changing index order when copying content takes place?

Comment: there is no any error..JSONObject doesn't follow any strict indexing,AFAIK

Comment: @Akki :) no need to look into code..

Comment: Can someone give me an example how to copy the content of a JSONObject without changing the index order?

Comment: It's not possible, because it makes no sense. The order doesn't matter.

Comment: The order does matter in my application. I'm drawing seats in a View Class and the problem is that all the seats have different position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone give me an example how to copy the content of a JSONObject without changing the index order?

It is not possible.

The `JSONObject` class stores the attributes in a hash table, so is not capable of representing the ordering of the attributes in a serial JSON representation.  That's OK because, the JSON spec says that the order of the attributes is not significant.

This comes from the origin of JSON, which is Javascript stntax for associative arrays / objects.  The entries in a Javascript associative have no defined / significant order.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is your problem, but JSON object properties don't have any intrinsic order.

```
{"a":"b", 
 "c":"d"}
```

is strictly equivalent to

```
{"c":"d", 
 "a":"b"}
```